# Eclipse Glassfish 3.1 adapter - SEQUENCE already exists error

Tags: eclipse, jpa, glassfish, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I have some problems with Eclipse server adapter for Glassfish 3.1. I am using the JPA auto generated identifiers. If the server is running and I have a create-and-drop policy for JPA, than each time the hot redeploy occurs I've got a big fat Eclipse error message thrown in my face:

> cannot Deploy MyWebApp Deployment Error for module: MyWebApp:
>
> PER01003: Deployment encountered SQL Exceptions:
> PER01000: Got SQLException executing statement "CREATE TABLE SEQUENCE (SEQ_NAME
> VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, SEQ_COUNT DECIMAL(38), PRIMARY KEY (SEQ_NAME))":
>
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "sequence" already exists

I am aware that this is just a Glassfish warning (damn old...: http://java.net/projects/glassfish/lists/persistence/archive/2006-11/message/221) and is not dangerous (it's because the drop.ddl is deleting just one sequence-table row instead of the whole table).

It's just a PITA to see this error popup each time I save a resource. Any ideas how to get rid of it without loosing create-and-drop functionality? At least to make it not disturbing while developing...

My persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="JPATestsCascadePU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/myDB</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" 
                              value="drop-and-create-tables" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Exemplary entity using auto generated ID:

```
@Entity
public class Website {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't like this answer: turn off the create-and-drop functionality after you do your initial Run on Server.

To be honest, create-and-drop seems like it will slow down redeployment... which is what is happening when you save a resource.

You can make the message appear less often by turning off automatic publishing...

Note: this issue applies to GlassFish integration plugins for Eclipse released before 2011-10-24 when they interact with GlassFish Server 3.1.1 and younger.

Comment: Thanks @vkraemer! You're probably right about the slowdown of redeployment. However, I used this setup to dynamically test JPA mappings, validation and interaction with transactions. These kind of applications are really small - I treat them just as a smoke-test and therefore I really liked this clean-recreate feature along with automatic publishing on each 'save'. It allows me to hit ctrl+s on changed class and forget about the rest.

I will eagerly for Monday :-) Thanks once again!

Comment: After your addition, the plugin works like a charm. Thanks a lot Vince!

Comment: I am using Glassfish 3.1.2 together with ant, to deploy and then redeploy my classes, so this error also seems to apply to the latest version of Glassfish.